# Why are overviews of an out-db postgis raster not out-db?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-raster, amazon-s3, map-overviews

I'm working on out-db postgis raster and have generated overviews, but why are the overviews generated of an out-db rasters stored in-db?
I have tried creating overviews both manually using St_CreateOverview and automatically when using raster2pgsql to insert the main raster table but both the times it generated out-db overviews. Is there any way to make overviews out-db as well?.[image]

Comment: Out-db rasters are read-only. I suppose they are always, but at least when the out-db rasters are stored into some cloud storage.